# How to make a good continuous graph in google sheets for clock values around 00:00 at night

Tags: datetime, google-sheets, graph, axis, yaxis

I have a dataset similar to below in google sheets that I want to plot in a line chart with dates on the x-axis and time on the y-axis.

Date            Time
2023-01-01      23:46
2023-01-02      00:32
2023-01-03      00:16
2023-01-04      22:37
2023-01-05      23:59

As you can see the times varies around midnight (00:00) which does not go well with a ordinary line chart since the 00:16 will be in the bottom of the chart and 23:59 will be at the top of the chart even though its only 17 minutes apart. How can I correct this to make a "better" and smoother graph?

I have managed to make it more smooth by either subtracting or adding 12h (23:59 becomes 11:59 and 00:16 becomes 12:16 for the actual y-values) so that the graph instead "oscillates" around noon instead of midnight, then the graphical representation is correct but the actual values on the y-axis is still wrong. How can I solve this problem to make a more smooth graph and correct time values on the y-axis?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A possible workaround is to add 1 if the time is after midnight (i.e. before 12 noon the next day, which is represented as 0.5 days):

```
=B2+(B2<0.5)
```

[image]